# how to interact between TCP/IP server and web app in J2EE

Tags: system-integration

I have a Web application based on Spring MVC 3.2 and TCP/IP Server written by Netty. Recently, I have got some requirement. It needs to be sent to the TCP/IP client via the TCP/IP server when a user wants to type some message on the Web browser. Of course, the message should be go to the Web application first and it will pass it to TCP/IP server and get back result. What would be the solution covering this requirement? I am having a look at AtiveMQ and Camel but not clear how to build these kind system.
Please let me get some clue or example.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement? Does user types input in a browser, it is processed by spring mvc application AND sent to TCP Server that delivers it to some TCP client? Do you need to wait for send / delivery result before constructing response to the browser?

Comment: Yes, exactly. User will wait for the response, and it needs to be displayed on the browser as well when the answer returns from the client.

Comment: It seems to me that it will be better to use AJAX for change state notifications. And once it is asynchronous you do not need another asynchronous layer like MQ or JMS to send a message over TCP. AJAX handler can directly open a stream and submit data.